# Determine the values of x, y, and z using one equation with three variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Solve for x, y, and z using one equation with three variables:

$xyz = x! + y! + z!$

where factorials are defined in the usual way, namely $n! = n(n-1)...2*1$

I'm not sure where to start with this question, any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $0<x<y<z$.  Then $xyz<z!<x!+y!+z!$.  Now... consider what happens if you allow equalities for some or all of these.

Comment: Alternate hint: note that $n!>n^3$ for all $n\geq 6$

Comment: @JMoravitz-You forgot to mention equality in your first statement.

Comment: @LoveInvariants Read the third sentence again.

Comment: This one $0<x<y<z$

Comment: @LoveInvariants by "*now...consider what happens if you allow equalities for some or all of these*" I mean 'Suppose instead that it were $0=x<y<z$ or $0<x=y<z$ or $0=x<y=z$ or...etc...'  I intentionally only explicitly solved one case and left the remaining cases alone for the OP or anyone else passing by to work on themselves and explicitly called attention to the fact that this was only one possible case and there are many other cases left to check.

Comment: Okay ............

Comment: For a related question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327352/overlinexyz-xyz).

Answer (score 1):

$xyz=x!+y!+z!$
$AM \ge GM$.
$\therefore$ $x^3+y^3+z^3\ge3x!+3y!+3z!$
$\Rightarrow$ $x^3+y^3+z^3-(3x!+3y!+3z!)\ge0$ -------- (1)
But we know that $k^3<k!$ (see above comment by JMoravitz) for $k>5$.

$\max(n^3-3n!)=9, n=3$. --------- (2)

That means that if we try to take value of $(x,y,z)$ greater than $4$ we won't be able to keep the above expression (expression (1), above) greater than $0$. As for $n=5$, expression(expression (2)) gives value smaller than $-18$ (which is the minimum value we can cancel out (by putting $n=3$) i.e. $18=2*9$).
Note: Expression (2) will keep on further decreasing for higher values of $n$.
Hence, it proves that $n\le4$.

Now find, value of expression (2) for $n=1,2,3,4$. ($0$ ins't possible because LHS will turn $0$).
Values of expression (2),
For $n=1$, Value $=-2$
$n=2$, Value $=2$
$n=3$, Value $=9$
$n=4$, Value $=-8$.

All possible triplets are $(1,2,2);(1,3,3);(1,2,3);(4,3,2);(4,3,3);(3,3,3);(2,2,2);(2,2,3);(3,3,2)$

Indeed a great achievement from $64$ possible triplets to $10$ (could be done faster if you have intuition and practised these steps.)

Bonus: $(x,y,z)$ aren't equal because for that $(x,y,z)$ should have $3$ as a factor and should be even. Reducing triplets to $8$.

This isn't answer you have to solve. :P

Answer (score 0):

So with the comments already given, two out of the three variables must be equal, and allocating the numbers 3,3,4 to the variables $x,y,z$ does it. There are 3 choices of doing that. And - that was also indicated in the comments - this is the only solution as for $x,y,z \geq 6$ no more solutions can be expected.